# Bunyan - duplicate logging in Node.js module

Tags: node.js, logging, bunyan

This logging duplication is happening in multiple projects and I am not sure why it's happening.

These two lines are logged:

```
[2016-01-25T21:28:25.019Z]  INFO: SmartConnect/11555 on CACSVML-13295.local (/Users/amills001c/WebstormProjects/lectal_all/algolia/oplog/tailing.js:19): about to start tailing...
[2016-01-25T21:28:25.019Z]  INFO: SmartConnect/11555 on CACSVML-13295.local (/Users/amills001c/WebstormProjects/lectal_all/algolia/oplog/tailing.js:19): about to start tailing...
```

but I know that the call to log this line is not being called twice. This is happening in multiple projects of mine, so I think there is some other problem.

My configuration for using Bunyan is like so:

```
var bunyan = require('bunyan');

module.exports =  bunyan.createLogger({
    name: 'Lectal-Logger',
    src: true,
    streams: [
        {
            level: 'info',
            stream: process.stdout
        },
        {
            level: 'error',
            stream: process.stderr
        }
    ]
});
```

the two duplicate logging entries above are both INFO level - so this should not be a case of stderr and stdout being sent to the same place (console/terminal in this case).

One clue is that if I change

```
log.info
```

to

```
log.debug
```

in my code, then the duplicate entry problem goes away. So, I might be missing something about how logging levels work.

Anyone have any ideas why I would see duplicate entries?

Comment: Hi Alex, you got any reason? For me log.error is giving duplicate entries?

Comment: it's been awhile, I don't remember if I have a solution or what the solution was, there was definitely something wrong with my configuration though. My error, not Bunyans.

Comment: try getting rid of the "streams" property, comment it out

Comment: Thanks. your questions here.. I got it here.. https://github.com/trentm/node-bunyan/issues/340

Comment: haha, yeah :) that's about right